# HIbernate doesn't create Foreign key for @OneToOne

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have two tables:

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = InfoEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private InfoEntity info;

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
public class InfoEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "info")
    private TestEntity test;
    
    ...
}
```

Basically I want to define a Foreign Key from `TestEntity` to `InfoEntity` by id fields which are the same in both tables. The problem is that when I check the database in IntelliJ Idea I don't see any Foreign Keys in keys section (checked both tables), only their PK's. Is something wrong with this code? I already set the property as it suggested in another similar question:

```
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: Are you auto-genetaring de DDL from java code or the database exists previouslly?

Comment: auto generating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *name* in `JoinColumn` has value *id*. Change it to **info_id** for example:

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity = InfoEntity.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="info_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private InfoEntity info;
```

You `TestEntity` already has a column `id`, so it has to has another name.